# How can I allocate more memory to the Windows VM that Docker for Windows is using when I run a Windows container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, artifactory, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

The Dockerfile for my image is very simple right now:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
RUN mkdir artifactory
ADD artifactory-pro-6.3.3 artifactory/
# systeminfo for debugging purposes only
RUN systeminfo
RUN C:\\artifactory\bin\artifactory
```

The output of the *systeminfo* call includes the following:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          N/A
Registered Organization:   N/A
Original Install Date:     12/5/2018, 4:52:49 PM
System Boot Time:          1/8/2019, 11:19:36 AM
System Manufacturer:       Microsoft Corporation
System Model:              Virtual Machine
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~3696 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V UEFI Release v2.5, 5/2/2018
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              N/A
Time Zone:                 (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     1,023 MB
Available Physical Memory: 597 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  1,023 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 612 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    411 MB
Page File Location(s):     N/A
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              N/A
Hotfix(s):                 3 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4132216
                           [02]: KB4465659
                           [03]: KB4471321
Network Card(s):           N/A
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

As you can see, the "Virtual Memory: Max Size" and "Total Physical Memory" attributes are set to be only 1023 MB. My *docker info* includes the following:

```
Containers: 24
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 24
Images: 35
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: lcow (linux) windowsfilter (windows)
 LCOW:
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 16299 (16299.637.amd64fre.rs3_release_svc.180808-1748)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 31.68GiB
```

I am using the following command to start my container:

```
docker run -it --name testing -m 8G artifactory-server:latest
```

Yet only 1G appears to be available. This is problematic, as when I attempt to start Artifactory, the Java Runtime Environment runs out of memory, and the container isn't spun up.

This is my first foray into Docker for Windows, so it's possible I have something misconfigured. Potential solutions that I have run into make references to VirtualBox, which I don't have due to its incompatibility with Hyper-V and running Windows containers.

I don't see the "Advanced" settings that some others seem to see, which makes me question whether I have the correct version of Docker at all. 
[Here is a picture of what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVX1s.png)

***EDIT**: Upon research, it appears that the reason I don't see the Shared Drives, Network, and Kubernetes tabs in the Settings menu is due to the fact that they're only available for Linux containers.*

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using WSL then the Advanced options are hidden from Docker for Windows; you need to specify the parameters in the Docker Engine tab JSON settings

Answer (score 0):

I am using docker desktop for windows(use hyper-v).
Steps to change memory:

1. right click docker desktop icon.
2. Settings
3. Resources
4. ADVANCED      you can change cpus/memory/swap in this subpage.
   [image]
5. Apply and restart.
6. Check effects:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Windows/Docker to the latest version. In my setup, with Windows version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.2604) and Docker version

```
docker version

    Client:
     Cloud integration: v1.0.29
     Version:           20.10.22
     API version:       1.41
     Go version:        go1.18.9
     Git commit:        3a2c30b
     Built:             Thu Dec 15 22:36:18 2022
     OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
     Context:           default
     Experimental:      true
    
    Server: Docker Desktop 4.16.3 (96739)
     Engine:
      Version:          20.10.22
      API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
      Go version:       go1.18.9
      Git commit:       42c8b31
      Built:            Thu Dec 15 22:31:10 2022
      OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
      Experimental:     false
```

the `-m 8G` switch is working properly:

```
docker run --rm -m 8G openjdk:11.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 systeminfo
    
    Host Name:                 AB026167DB57
    OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
    OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
    OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
    OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
    OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
    Registered Owner:          N/A
    Registered Organization:   N/A
    Product ID:                00377-90000-00001-AA523
    Original Install Date:     1/6/2022, 6:35:40 PM
    System Boot Time:          2/24/2023, 7:42:54 AM
    System Manufacturer:       Microsoft Corporation
    System Model:              Virtual Machine
    System Type:               x64-based PC
    Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                               [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13 GenuineIntel ~2904 Mhz
    BIOS Version:              Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.0, 11/1/2019
    Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
    System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
    Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
    System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
    Input Locale:              N/A
    Time Zone:                 N/A
    Total Physical Memory:     8,703 MB
                               ^^^^^^^^
    Available Physical Memory: 8,230 MB
    Virtual Memory: Max Size:  8,703 MB
                               ^^^^^^^^
    Virtual Memory: Available: 8,222 MB
    Virtual Memory: In Use:    481 MB
    Page File Location(s):     N/A
    Domain:                    WORKGROUP
    Logon Server:              N/A
    Hotfix(s):                 4 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                               [01]: KB4054590
                               [02]: KB4132216
                               [03]: KB5005698
                               [04]: KB5009546
    Network Card(s):           N/A
    Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Answer (score -2):

In the "advanced" section of your docker daemon settings you can update the memory and CPU settings:

[image]

You can see all the details [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#advanced)

Comment: I just edited my post to mention this:

I don't see those options, which makes me question whether I even have the version of Docker that I need to do this. I see only the General, Proxies, Daemon, Diagnose & Feedback, and Reset tabs. 
_**EDIT**: Upon research, it appears that the reason I don't see the Shared Drives, Network, and Kubernetes tabs in the Settings menu is due to the fact that they're only available for Linux containers._

Comment: I'm downvoting this reply because OP specifically asked for problem with windows container. But the screen posted here is only applicable for linux container mode.